# Type Mismatch in ML List.filter

Tags: sml

I am trying to write a simple filter function in ML. The idea is that the function `only_capitals` takes a list of strings and returns a list of strings, with only the strings that start with a capital letter. Here is my implementation, but I am getting a type-error that I do not understand:

```
fun only_capitals (strs : string list) =
   let
     fun isCapitalized (str) = Char.isUpper(String.sub(str, 0))
   in
     List.filter(isCapital, strs)
   end
```

Here is the error:

```
hw3provided.sml:5.18-5.27 Error: unbound variable or constructor: isCapital
hw3provided.sml:5.6-5.34 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: 'Z -> bool
  operand:         _ * string list
  in expression:
    List.filter (<errorvar>,strs)
val it = () : unit
```

Comment: So what's the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error is caused by a typo; "isCapital" is not the name of the function you defined.

The second error looks extra strange because of the first error – the type `_` refers to the type of `isCapital`.
If you fix the first error, the second should look more like

```
Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: 'Z -> bool
  operand:         (string -> bool) * string list
  in expression:
    List.filter (isCapitalized,strs)
```

What the compiler is trying to say is that you're passing the pair `(isCapitalized,strs)` to `filter` where it expects a function of type `'Z -> bool`.

If you [look at the type of `List.filter`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html), you'll notice that it is `('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list` – it's a curried function.

What you should write is

```
fun only_capitals (strs : string list) =
   let
     fun isCapitalized (str) = Char.isUpper(String.sub(str, 0))
   in
     List.filter isCapitalized strs
   end
```

Comment: Thank you. Completely forgot about currying.